# How to display a list of categories

Tags: categories

I'm trying to set up a list of categories with clickable links to that category.
I've looked at:

- [Display list of Sub-Categories and the posts they contain, within one main Category](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28469/display-list-of-sub-categories-and-the-posts-they-contain-within-one-main-categ)

and am not quite sure where to put the code or how to access it on the page.

I understand the PHP well enough - it's pretty straightforward, I'm just relatively new to WP and need some help implementing.

Comment: Wrap code that you got in link above in a function and add it to functions.php, then use that function wherever you want using hooks, shortcode or in template file.

Answer (score 3):

I will show you how to display a list of categories in WordPress and also mark the active category, see code below:

```
<?php
// Get the current queried object
$term    = get_queried_object();
$term_id = ( isset( $term->term_id ) ) ? (int) $term->term_id : 0;

$categories = get_categories( array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'category', // Taxonomy to retrieve terms for. We want 'category'. Note that this parameter is default to 'category', so you can omit it
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'parent'     => 0,
    'hide_empty' => 0, // change to 1 to hide categores not having a single post
) );
?>

<ul>
    <?php
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) 
    {
        $cat_ID        = (int) $category->term_id;
        $category_name = $category->name;

        // When viewing a particular category, give it an [active] class
        $cat_class = ( $cat_ID == $term_id ) ? 'active' : 'not-active';

        // I don't like showing the [uncategoirzed] category
        if ( strtolower( $category_name ) != 'uncategorized' )
        {
            printf( '%3$s',
                esc_attr( $cat_class ),
                esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ),
                esc_html( $category->name )
            );
        }
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

## Notes about the code above:

[get_queried_object()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) retrieve the currently-queried object. For example:

- if you're on a single post, it will return the post object
- if you're on a page, it will return the page object
- if you're on an archive page, it will return the post type object
- if you're on a category archive, it will return the category object
- if you're on an author archive, it will return the author object
- etc.

But there are some implications when using `get_queried_object()`, you should not expect it to return a post type object even when [is_post_type_archive()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive) is true. Check it out for more info.

Also, note that `get_queried_object()` is a wrapper for  `$wp_query->get_queried_object()`, so it returns a WP object data type.

## get_categories()

[get_categories()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) retrieve list of category objects. Currently accepts only one parameter - `$args`. The $args parameter specifies a list of arguments that should be used to retrieve categories. See [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) for additional options.

However, to get the category for a particular posts here's a simple function I wrote: [How to get list of categories for a post](https://johnzenith.wordpress.com/2019/01/04/how-to-get-list-of-categories-for-a-post/)

Answer (score 2):

As per the linked WPSE thread, and the [accepted answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/28646/22728), the code is (copied & pasted):

```
$categories =  get_categories('child_of=31');  
foreach  ($categories as $category) {
    //Display the sub category information using $category values like $category->cat_name
    echo '<h2>'.$category->name.'</h2>';
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach (get_posts('cat='.$category->term_id) as $post) {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';   
    }  
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

As for us (the WordPress developers) [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org) is the key for most of the basics. So according to WordPress Codex:

- [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) does query for all the categories of a site, and returns an array.
- Similarly [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) does query for all the posts of a site, and returns an array.

And they both are the shortcut of [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). You can get all their possible parameters from the Codex pages. As you are a PHP enthusiast, you know how the code is functioning: `$categories` is taking all the categories and for every category `get_posts()` is taking its posts.

So it's very similar to a mySQL query and a foreach loop in raw PHP. You can put this code into any of your WP site's active theme's [template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_into_Templates) pages. [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) can give you a detail insight.

As per your title of the Question is:

> *How to display a list of categories*

The answer can be:

```
$categories =  get_categories();
echo '<ul>';
foreach  ($categories as $category) {
  echo '<li>'. $category->cat_name .'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

> *am not quite sure where to put the code or how to access it on the page.*

I've already said, try putting the code into `index.php`, `front-page.php`, ... anywhere. The key concept is: it's just a SQL Query and a useful `foreach` loop of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

This method enables you to exclude any category simply by adding the cat i.d to the code.

Here's a better way to add a list of categories conditionally from your child themes functions file in any WordPress or theme specific hook location:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpsites_list_cats' );
function wpsites_list_cats($content) {
if( is_singular('post') && is_main_query() ) {
$args = array(
'orderby' => 'name',
'exclude' => '',
'include' => '',
'parent' => 0
);
$categories = get_categories( $args );
echo'<nav id="primary-navigation" class="primary-navigation" role="navigation">';
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' .  $category->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo'</nav>';
return $content;
    }
}
```

Here's the result

[image]

And here's the result if you want to use the existing styling from the Twenty Fourteens navigation menus which the above code includes.

[image]

The code also enables you to include specific categories or exclude any using the cat i.d's

You could also [create a custom widget area](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/131766/9884) and use the native WordPress category widget.

Simply change the [the_content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) hook to change the location of the categories list.

Modified from [this source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)

Answer (score 0):

Or use the [List Categories plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/list-categories/) with its own configurable shortcode, which behaves as a shortcut to the `wp_list_categories( array|string $args = '' )` [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/).

You can configure its arguments as documente there as well.